# Angular material conflict with dirPagination

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, dirpagination

I am using the **dirPagination**(angular plugin) and the **angular material** library in one of my projects.

**Description of issue**: Including the angular material library cases the pagination directive to pause while switching the records from one page to another

**Steps to reproduce**: create a simple page and include the angular material library and the module in you app using the `dirPagination`,now switch across the pages

**Expected result**: There should not be any delay in displaying the records.

**Actual result**: It shows all the records at once an then hide the records not required to be shown.

[Link for plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8ByRaRbvZJMEnW4FakoO?p=preview)

Comment: In your plunker, when I click in any page it shows the record and after like 2 seconds it just disappears.. is that the problem?

Comment: Yes this is the main problem i am facing by just adding the **ngMaterial** module